# The conflict between your own styles and gutenberg

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Is it possible to disable the default gutenberg styles? My problem is that after inserting the `<!-- wp: list -->` tag into the page code, wordpress removes the styles that have been assigned to the list from my style.css. I will add that I have disabled the handler wp-block-library in the functions.php file.

Ultimately, I would like to remain flexible in modifying content through the Wordpress panel, but with my own styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can dequeue the default block style which is enqueued with handle `wp-block-library`. Add the following to your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_styles_block', 100 );
function remove_styles_block() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
}
```

Comment: I've added before, but that doesn't solve my problem. When I mark a tag of my choice, e.g. ```<p>``` with the gutenberg tag ```<! - wp: paragraph ->``` it automatically resets my previously created styles.